# Ignore a line in sorbet

Tags: sorbet

How can I ignore type checking for specific line?

```
if self.params.present?
  self.params = self.params.gsub(/aaa/, "bbb")
end
```

In this example self.params is not `nil`, but sorbet still show error.
How can I disable type checker for specific line?

UPD: one more example

```
class CC
  def a1
    a = open("123")
    return 123
  ensure
    if a
      p a # => This code is unreachable https://srb.help/7006. Why??
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a handful of ways to do this, all with varying degrees of "wow I'm really blowing away a lot of static type information."

They're all documented here, under Escape Hatches:

https://sorbet.org/docs/troubleshooting#escape-hatches

Unlike many other gradual type checkers / linters, Sorbet does not have a way to silence errors with a comment, and is unlikely to ever add such a feature. Instead, Sorbet allows silencing errors by either:

- Lowering the `typed:` level of a file, i.e., from `typed: true` to `typed: false` (see [here](https://sorbet.org/docs/static) for the consequences).
- Using `T.unsafe` to convert some expression to `T.untyped`.

(Using comments to silence errors from a type checker is often the wrong solution, because when there's a type error, it usually has a lot of downstream effects that might cause their own errors, which become even more confusing because the real source of the error has been silenced!)

Comment: How to apply it for `This code is unreachable` error?
For now sorbet still buggy and support from other libs still need a lot of work. I don't want to make code ugly just to make it validate correctly